# Script: forward all emails from inbox, after users sends 'request' (Outlook 2003)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, script

I am looking for a Outlook (2003) script.

**What I need:**
I want to forward all my emails from mailbox-A (from a PC) to mailbox-B (on my phone).
The catch is: This rule should only run, when I send a 'request' to mailbox-A.

**What I did:**
I've created two rules in Outlook 2003.

Rule1- This rule forwards all emails from mailbox-A to mailbox-B. This rule works, but it is not automated (only runs when I press the button 'run rules'). 
I only want to receive emails 'when I want to'.

Rule2- I've created a second rule in Outlook. 
This rule starts (itself) when mailbox-A receives an email with 'get_mail' as email subject.

**My goal:**
I want rule2 to start a script. Obviously, this script should run rule1.

**Result:**
All emails from mailbox-A are forwarded to mailbox-B.

**Backgroud:** 
My goal is to read my work emails on my phone, commuting between work and home.
By sending an email from my phone to my PC (with email subject get_mail), my PC 
(mailbox-A) forwards all emails to my phone (mailbox-B).

Is this possible using VBA? And how should the code look like? 
I have no experience with scripting, but I'm good with PCs and software in general. So I should be able install it when somebody supplies to the code.

(**p.s.** It is not possible to simply install the pop/imap account on my phone)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have one rule trigger another rule. Here is a VBA procedure for Outlook that should work:

```vb
Sub RunRuleToForwardEmail(MyMail As MailItem)

    Dim st As Outlook.Store
    Dim myRule As Outlook.Rule

    ' get default store (where rules live)
    Set st = Application.Session.DefaultStore
    ' get rule
    Set myRule = st.GetRules("change_this_to_whatever_the_the_name_of_rule1_is") 'change this line
    myRule.Execute

End Sub
```

Remember to change this text: `change_this_to_whatever_the_the_name_of_rule1_is`.

Once you save your Outlook VBA Project, edit the actions of rule2. You should then be able to choose the above script in the list of options.

Comment: Thanks for you prompt answer.

THe name of the rule is actually 'rule1'.
So I changed your bit of the code into 'Set myRule = st.GetRules("rule1")'.

Is that correct? I was able to select the script as action in rule2. Unfortunately it did not work. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: Hm, yes that's correct. I tried it myself and it worked (although my rule1 just categorised my mail, didn't forward it). Add this extra code at the beginning of the procedure: `MsgBox "The RunRuleToForwardEmail VBA procedure is running"`. Put this on it's own line before the first Dim statement. Then try it. If the code is running properly, a message should appear in Outlook to alert you. If this message doesn't appear, then something must be wrong with the rule that is meant to trigger it.

Comment: No success :-(. Code is as followed:

[Link]Sub RunRuleToForwardEmail(MyMail As MailItem)

MsgBox "The RunRuleToForwardEmail VBA procedure is running"

    Dim st As Outlook.Store
    Dim myRule As Outlook.Rule
    Dim rl As Outlook.Rule

    ' get default store (where rules live)
    Set st = Application.Session.DefaultStore
    ' get rule
    Set myRule = st.GetRules(rule1)
    myRule.Execute

End Sub

Comment: Aha - the text `rule1` has to be surrounded by quote marks: `"rule1"`. The message should still have appeared, did it?

Comment: I added the quote marks, nothing changed. I did not see any message either. I added to rule1 'set flag color green'. And to rule2 'set flag color purple'. When the email with subject get_mails comes arrives, this email gets a purple flag. Any other way to create a 'check'?

Comment: I think I know what it is! Rule1 is not checked/not active/not enabled. Rule1 is disabled (else it would constantly forward all incoming emails, and that is not what I want). Is their an option to run an rule that is NOT active/enabled?

Comment: I'm testing this on Outlook 2010, and the code runs rule1, even if it's not enabled. So I think the main issue is why rule2 isn't triggering the code to run on your PC. I'll see if I can test it in Outlook 2003. In the meantime, can you open the VBA editor and temporarily edit the first line of code to `Sub RunRuleToForwardEmail()`. Then press F5 to execute the procedure. See if any errors come up.

Comment: Ah wait, I got this error message after pressing F5:

---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Basic
---------------------------
The macros in this project are disabled.  Please refer to the online help or documentation of the host application to determine how to enable macros.------------- I've changed the security level for macro's in Outlook to 'Low'. Did not work either...or should I change the security settings somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response @user316237. Did you end up getting this working? After you set the security setting to Low, did you get the exact same error message?